# Is there someway to set a breakpoint if an unhandled exception occurs in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, unhandled-exception

Is there someway to set a breakpoint if an unhandled exception occurs in Android Studio?
I want the debugger to stop at the line that causes the exception. I think this is very obvious but I am not able to find how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Run or Logcat and there will be information on the type of error and the line number where the error occured

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).